# Saving/Storing pymatgen Structures

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, pymatgen

I'm currently dealing with a material science dataset having various information.

In particular, I have a column 'Structure' with several `pymatgen.core.Structure` objects.

I would like to save/store this dataset as `.csv` file or something similar but the problem is that after having done that and reopening, the pymatgen structures lose their `type` becoming just formatted strings and I cannot get back to their initial `pymatgen.core.Structure` data type.

Any hints on how to that? I'm searching on `pymatgen` documentation but haven't been lucky for now..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange might be a good place to ask this question as more experts are active there.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://pymatgen.org/usage.html#side-note-as-dict-from-dict):

> #### Side-note : as_dict / from_dict
>
> As you explore the code, you may
> notice that many of the objects have an as_dict method and a from_dict
> static method implemented. For most of the non-basic objects, we have
> designed pymatgen such that it is easy to save objects for subsequent
> use. While python does provide pickling functionality, pickle tends to
> be extremely fragile with respect to code changes. Pymatgen’s as_dict
> provide a means to save your work in a more robust manner, which also
> has the added benefit of being more readable. The dict representation
> is also particularly useful for entering such objects into certain
> databases, such as MongoDb. This as_dict specification is provided in
> the monty library, which is a general python supplementary library
> arising from pymatgen.
>
> The output from an as_dict method is always json/yaml serializable. So
> if you want to save a structure, you may do the following:
>
> ```py
> with open('structure.json','w') as f:
>     json.dump(structure.as_dict(), f)
> ```
>
> Similarly, to get the structure back from a json, you can do the  following to restore the
> structure (or any object with a as_dict method) from the json as
> follows:
>
> ```py
> with open('structure.json', 'r') as f:
>     d = json.load(f)
>     structure = Structure.from_dict(d)
> ```
>
> You may replace any of the above json commands with yaml in the PyYAML package to create a yaml
> file instead. There are certain tradeoffs between the two choices.
> JSON is much more efficient as a format, with extremely fast
> read/write speed, but is much less readable. YAML is an order of
> magnitude or more slower in terms of parsing, but is more human
> readable.

See also https://pymatgen.org/usage.html#montyencoder-decoder and https://pymatgen.org/usage.html#reading-and-writing-structures-molecules

Answer (score 1):

pymatgen.core.structure object can be stored with only some sort of fixed format, for example, cif, vasp, xyz... so maybe you, first, need to store your structure information to cif or vasp. and open it and preprocess to make it "csv" form with python command.(hint : using python string-related command).